# View a buffer in full screen mode

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm using buffers with multiple split windows in Neovim. Is there any solution that I can open a buffer in the full-screen mode and move it back split mode after that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit of confusion in your question between "buffers", "windows", and what you call "full-screen mode".

- A "buffer" is Vim's exact equivalent of a "document" in more normal programs. It can be hidden or displayed in one or more windows.
- A "window" is a view into a buffer. You always have at least one window displaying one buffer.
- A "tab page" is a collection of windows. You always have at least one tab page with one window displaying one buffer.

So, assuming you are in a tab page, with `n` windows laid out the way you want…

- You can press `<C-w>T` to *move* the current *window* to a new tab page. Since the window is the only one in that new tab page, you get that "full-screen mode", but Vim doesn't remember the previous layout so there is no easy way to recreate it.

  See `:help ctrl-w_T`.
- You can issue the command `:tab sp`. When you do `:split`, the current window is split in two, with each window displaying the same buffer. If you prepend it with `:tab`, a new tab page is created and the new window is opened in that tab page. Therefore `:tab split` can be understood as "split the current window into a new tab page".

  The advantage of this over `<C-w>T` is that the original layout, in the orignal tab page, is not changed so there is no need to "move anything back". If you want to get back to the original tab page and its layout, just switch to the original tab page with `:tabn#` and close the extraneous tab page with `:tabc#`:

  ```
  :tab sp
  :tabn# or `g<tab>`
  :tabc#
  ```

  Note that, if you are starting with only one tab page, the `:tabn#`/`:tabc#` dance can be reduced to `:tabo#`.

  If that's something you need to do often, you might want to create custom mappings to simplify the process:

  ```
  nnoremap <key> :tab split<CR>
  nnoremap <otherkey> :tabnext#\|tabclose#<CR>
  ```

  See `:help :split`, `:help :tab`, `:help :tabnext`, `:help :tabclose`, and `:help :tabonly`.
- Or you can look for a third-party plugin that abstracts all this.